# Enable Auto Scroll in Elastic Content Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Using Elastic Content Slider to showcase featured deals on my site http://freekishopping.in

You can see demo on my site

Bu this slider is not scrolling automatic means next slide  is not coming automatic. I want to  make it auto scroll after a fixes interval of 400ms.

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: You need to make an attempt trying to solve the problem.

Comment: 1) What is your objective? 2) What did you try? 3) What was the result of that?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb i dont know anything about js

Comment: @boolean my objective is to make that slider auto slide, i dont know anything about Jquery so i didnt tried

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do..

First, Fix the `href` for the links to be unique

```
<a href="#slide1"> ... </a>
<a href="#slide2"> ... </a>
<a href="#slide3"> ... </a>
<a href="#slide4"> ... </a>
<a href="#slide5"> ... </a>
```

Second, write an infinite recursive call to simulate clicking the unique links.

```
var slideCount = 1;

function clickingLoop(){

    if(slideCount == 5){
         slideCount = 1;
     }

     $("a[href$=#slide"+slideCount+"]")[0].click();

     slideCount++;

     setTimeout(clickingLoop, 1500);   // or 400ms
}


clickingLoop();
```

Comment: This might need more CSS tweaking to simulate highlighting the icons from the list